# java.io.FileNotFoundException for the url which was working fine yesterday

Tags: java, api, httpurlconnection

I was able to get the data from a get request yesterday, But today if I call the same api I get

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.quikr.com/jobs/v1/zwayam/application?companyName=test&jobId=123
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.zwayam.controller.QuikrDataPoint.getJobApplicationForQuikrJobs(QuikrDataPoint.java:162)
at com.zwayam.controller.QuikrDataPoint.main(QuikrDataPoint.java:54)
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.quikr.com/jobs/v1/zwayam/application?companyName=test&jobId=123
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.zwayam.controller.QuikrDataPoint.getJobApplicationForQuikrJobs(QuikrDataPoint.java:159)
    ... 1 more

I cant access this api directly in browser coz there are some application headers to be set
Is this a coding issue or the api issue?

```
    String urlstr = "https://api.quikr.com/jobs/v1/zwayam/application?";

        List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("companyName", "test"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jobId", "123"));
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

        url = new URL(urlstr + paramString);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        String todaysDate = format.format(cal.getTime());
        String emailId = "roshan@zwayam.com";
        String data = appId + emailId + todaysDate;
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(tokenKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(signingKey);
        String signature = toHexString(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/JSON");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Quikr-App-Id", "890");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Quikr-Token-Id", tokenId.toString());
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Quikr-Signature-v2", signature);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

This is the section which calls the api, The response code I am getting is 404

Comment: I think that we need to see QuikrDataPoint.java:162, but usually FileNotFound only means one thing

Comment: *The response code I am getting is 404* Your story has changed.  Surely you know what `404` means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the api,They fixed it and now its working fine :)